# Need to Make a Parse Cloud Code Job to Reset all Objects at a Certain Time of Day

Tags: class, object, parse-platform, cloud

I currently have an app powered by parse that monitors the wait times for a certain amusement park. On parse, each ride has its own class file and in each class there is an object with a string entitled "waitTime" which has a string that has the most recent wait time submitted. I would like to use cloud code to reset all of the waitTime sections of each object to "0" at 1:00 AM each morning. I have no experience with Cloud Code or anything like it. How would I go about doing something like this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a job that runs every 5 minutes, comparing the current server time to any scheduled times (e.g. 1am, including timezone issues), and if it matches run that task (in your case resetting the "waitTime").

It is common to have this single master job trigger multiple different tasks (functions in your cloud code) using different rules such as time or a manual job queue, that's why I suggest this pattern.